# As3 - I Simply cannot remove loader child no matter what

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have loaded an external SWF to my timeline using a common loader method. The SWF is Jwplayer and it is polling a live rtmp stream. Here is the snippet I used to load it successfully.

```
var c4:Loader = new Loader();
var c4req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("player.swf");
var c4flashvars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
c4flashvars.streamer = "rtmp://myserver";
c4flashvars.file = "live"
c4req.data = c4flashvars;
c4.load(c4req);
addChild(c4)
```

Now, the player loads fine. It begins to poll a live stream, too. However, no matter what I try I cannot remove this child from the stage. I have tried the following:

```
removeChild(c4);
c4.unloadAndStop();
```

For testing, I am calling these from a timer/event listener/function combo. I traced it to make sure it was being fired, and it is. However the player just sits there on the stage and refuses to leave. Output isn't throwing any errors. I *half* suspect that because it's polling a live stream that the loader never sees the external SWF as *fully* loaded. But that's just a hunch.

The overall scope of this little project is to load the player, check for an event, and re-load the player (unload, and reload). If anyone could help me understand this, get past this, or is feeling generous enough to show me the light; I'd appreciate it greatly. I've put a solid day into messing around with this and searching. I'm just not grasping something. Thanks!

Comment: What happens it you first call `.close()` on the loader?

Comment: @SushiHangover Hi, I called that in a button using:

 'loader.close()' (correct?) 

And received Error: 

Error #2029: This URLStream object does not have a stream opened. at flash.display::Loader/close() at cs4container_3_fla::MainTimeline/unloadSwf() 

Desipte there being a live stream playing right in front of me. The only thing that makes a dent is using 'loader.unloadAndStop(true)' and that will end the stream and return a play icon to jwplayer. But the player is very much on the stage still. Sorry if this formatting is frustrating, i'm new here. :)

Comment: @matthews If you think that the problem is coming from the live stream try to load just the swf without any stream or with a local video then try again to remove it ...

Comment: It's just a scope loss. He creates the variable c4 inside a method and then he can never reference it again.

Comment: @BotMaster Let me ask this questions, then. Is there a way to do this and maintain the reach? Or am I wasting my time? Thanks.

Comment: Of course set your variable c4 as a member of a class or outside the method so it can have a larger scope. Then you can reference that variable from within your other methods.